# How to implement callback methods inside classes (PHP)

Tags: php, class, arrays, callback, methods

I need to use a class callback method on an array inside another method (the callback function belongs to the class).

```
class Database {

      public function escape_string_for_db($string){
             return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
      }

      public function escape_all_array($array){
             return array_map($array,"$this->escape_string_for_db");
      }
}
```

Is this the right way to go about that? (I mean, in terms of the second parameter passed to `array_map`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you want to [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), but [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
return array_map(array($this, 'escape_string_for_db'), $array);
```

but then again, you can just as well do

```
return array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $array);
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the two confused.

Answer (score 0):

`array_filter` deletes elements which does not satisfy the predicate. Do you mean `array_map`?

```
return array_map(array($this, "escape_string_for_db"), $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You can check in the same function weather your parameter is string or array.

```
class Database {

  public function escape_string_for_db($data)
  {
    if( !is_array( $data ) )
    {
      $data =mysql_real_escape_string($data);   
    }
    else
    {
      //Self call function 
      $data = array_map(array( 'Database ', 'escape_string_for_db' ), $data );
    }
  return $data;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplest solution would be to to pass the method as the callback - see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback

Alternatively, write a wrapper function:

```
function wrap_callback($target, $use_obj=false)
{
  static $obj;
  if ($use_obj) {
     if (method_exists($target, 'callback')) {
        $obj=$target;
        return true;
     } else {
        trigger_error("callback declared for something with no callback method");
        return false;
     }
  }
  return $obj->callback($target);
}
```

Then:

```
class Database {

  public callback($string){
         return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
  }

  public function escape_all_array($array){
         wrap_callback($this, true); // register callback
         return array_filter($array,"wrap_calback");
  }
}
```

C.

Comment: No offense, but this is overcomplicated and using static in functions is bad style